# home server drive setup

Tags: server, partitioning

I am trying to configure a home server that will do following things:

1. backup my and my wife's Mac's to separate shares/partitions that are limited in space usage
2. have a network file sharing that will allow access from mac, windows and linux machines
3. plex media server that also uses previous shares as media sources.

I have one 3TB drive and I don't know how to set it up.  Mainly my problem is what file system should I be using and what the structure of the drive should be.

I was trying to set up two 400GB partitions for backups and rest for share, but I'm not sure if it is needed.  Could someone help me with resolving the drive setup issue, so I could proceed with the setup because this is a wall I can't get through at the moment.

Comment: Is the 3TB drive a second drive separate from the boot volume? And for the Mac backup, are you using Time Machine for that? I don't know if the two systems can cohabitate on the same setup, but running FreeNAS and Plex might be the route to pursue.

Comment: yes i have separate 80GB drive for the system. Also for mac i do plan using Time Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up your disk using LVM2 so you can make virtual partitions and resize them as you need. Logical volumes are easy to set up, remove and resize. Without the hassle that ordinary partitions have, like you have set up now.  I would also consider using quota systems in the file system instead of different partitions. File system doesn't matter that much, use ext4 would be a safe bet.

As to sharing file systems I would look into Samba and NFS. Samba for MS Windows machines and NFS for Mac and Linux.

Media, I have no clue as I never used Plex.

Comment: So as I understand it doesn't matter what file system i use, what matters is what service i am using for the shares? Is there a way to do shares for all systems at once? I would need them to be accessible from  every system.

Comment: Yes, the service is how you share file areas (directories) to other machines.  And as I wrote, you can make same file area shared with different services, like `/srv/media/music` shared with both Samba and NFS.  Which system has access to which file area depends on how you configure Samba and NFS.  You can restrict access to a subset of machines/IP-numbers/user accounts.  How depends on which service you uses, samba or NFS.

Answer (score 0):

Personally what I'd look into in your case (for the purposes of simplicity) is to just create one partition for your network shares and use filesystem quotas to manage who can use up how much of that disk slice.